# DB Design for intranet - Company Table

Tags: database

I am designing an intranet application. This intranet is for a parent company which will have multiple sub companies under it. Each employee will belong to a company. I need to store only the name of the company as of now.

Now to maintain external relations to partners and clients we need to store their company. Here also, I need to store only the name.

My questions is - Is it better to keep these in two separate tables one company table for internal and the other for external? Or is it better to have one table and identify internal and external companies with a FLAG.

The generic question being if two tables have the same structure but belong to differ
Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Better*, in a sense of normalized database design, would be to have one company table and second table of company types instead of a flag column. You'll be able to distinguish external partners later without having to add another flag.

Comment: Thank you! I will create another table to hold the company types.